# How to create a directory in user space in a Linux kernel module

Tags: c, linux, module, kernel, kernel-module

The following will create a file in user space but how can I create a directory?

```
struct file *filp = filp_open("/home/myuser/Desktop/newfile", O_CREAT, S_IRWXU);
```

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mkdir.2.html

Answer (score 0):

The best way I know how is to use:

```
mkdir("your/directory", 0700);
```

David Heffernan's comment shows the specifics.

Edit:
This page will show you the different mode parameters you can give for your directory and what they do.

http://osdir.com/ml/linux.c-programming/2002-06/msg00069.html

Answer (score 0):

Just set `O_DIRECTORY` in `filp_open` flags.